# Adding class on an image click?

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

```
function updateOption(selection, option) {
        jQuery('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery("#msg").offset().top
        }, 800);
        jQuery('.'+selection).each(function() {
            jQuery("img."+selection).removeClass("optionSelected");
        });
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../v1_include/v1_session_boutique.inc.php",
            data: selection + "=" + option,
            success: function(msg){
                jQuery('#msg').fadeIn('fast');
                var List = document.getElementById('msg');
                List.innerHTML = msg;
                  jQuery(".StoreMsgPanier").animate( { opacity: 0.25 }, 1000)
                    .animate( { opacity: 1 }, 1000);
            }
        });
}


<p>Option 1</p>
<div id="opt3">
    <a href="javascript:updateOption('select_1_3','1-5-1');"><img src="../v1_images_option/crop/5_1.jpg" alt="" style="margin:2px;padding:5px;border:1px solid #D6D6D6" class="select_1_3 optionSelected" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:updateOption('select_1_3','1-6-1');"><img src="../v1_images_option/crop/6_1.jpg" alt="" style="margin:2px;padding:5px;border:1px solid #D6D6D6" class="select_1_3" /></a>
</div>
<p>Option 2</p>
<div id="opt2">
    <a href="javascript:updateOption('select_1_2','1-3-1');"><img src="../v1_images_option/crop/3_1.jpg" alt="" style="margin:2px;padding:5px;border:1px solid #D6D6D6" class="select_1_2" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:updateOption('select_1_2','1-4-1');"><img src="../v1_images_option/crop/4_1.jpg" alt="" style="margin:2px;padding:5px;border:1px solid #D6D6D6" class="select_1_2" /></a>
</div>
```

This code works fine but how can I, after removing all 'optionSelected' class, add 'optionSelected' **ONLY to the image I just clicked** ?

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either pass `this` from the caller and use it inside the function,

**Markup:** Added `this` to the `updateOption` function call

```
    <a href="javascript:updateOption('select_1_3','1-5-1', this);">
```

**JS:** Changed to `_this.find(..`

```
  function updateOption(selection, option, _this) {
    //..
    //...
       $(_this).parent().find("img").removeClass("optionSelected"); //remove class for all images
       $(_this).find("img").addClass("optionSelected"); //add class to the image inside the link
```

Alternatively, It is good practice to use unobtrusive way.. See below,

**Markup:** Added `this` to the `updateOption` function call

```
<p>Option 1</p>
<div id="opt3">
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" data-opt="1-5-1" data-sel="select_1_3"><img src="../v1_images_option/crop/5_1.jpg" alt="Image" class="select_1_3 img_style optionSelected" /></a>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-opt="1-6-1" data-sel="select_1_3"><img src="../v1_images_option/crop/6_1.jpg" alt="Image" class="select_1_3 img_style" /></a>
</div>
<p>Option 2</p>
<div id="opt2">
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" data-opt="1-3-1" data-sel="select_1_2"><img src="../v1_images_option/crop/3_1.jpg" alt="Image" class="select_1_2 img_style" /></a>
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" data-opt="1-4-1" data-sel="select_1_2"><img src="../v1_images_option/crop/4_1.jpg" alt="Image" class="select_1_2 img_style" /></a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img_style { margin:2px;padding:5px;border:1px solid #D6D6D6; }
```

**And finally the JS:** Bunch of modification, please try to understand it before you implement it.

```
$(function() {
    $('.img_style').click(function() {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#msg").offset().top
        }, 800);

        var $this = $(this);        

        $this //current link
        .closest('div') //will return you the enclosing div lets say <div id="opt2">
        .find('img') //find all images inside <div id="opt2">
        .removeClass("optionSelected"); //remove class

        $this.addClass('optionSelected');

        var $parent = $this.parent();

        var option = $parent.attr('data-opt'); //will return you the option
        var selection = $parent.attr('data-sel');

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../v1_include/v1_session_boutique.inc.php",
            data: selection + "=" + option,
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#msg').fadeIn('fast').html(msg);

                $(".StoreMsgPanier").animate({
                    opacity: 0.25
                }, 1000).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/tkRTN/1/) -> To show that the option and selection is retrieved.

Comment: Well I already found the way to remove the class. I just need to ADD 'optionSelected' to the image clicked. This code is not working. Thanks for your help...

Comment: @Vegas : ../v1_include/v1_session_boutique.inc.php?undefined=undefined -> option is undefined

Comment: @Vegas : var option = $(this).parent().attr('data-opt');

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#id_of_image').on('click', function() {
  $('img').removeClass('optionSelected');
  $(this).addClass('optionSelected');
});
```